# Ruby concatenate strings and add spaces

Tags: ruby, string, concatenation

I have 4 string variables `name, quest, favorite_color, speed` that might be empty.  I want to concatenate them all together, putting spaces between those that aren't empty.  Simplicity of the code, i.e how simple is to to look at and understand, is more important than speed.

So:

```
name = 'Tim'
quest = 'destroy'
favorite_color = 'red'
speed = 'fast'
```

becomes

```
'Tim destroy red fast'
```

and

```
name = 'Steve'
quest = ''
favorite_color = ''
speed = 'slow'
```

becomes:

```
'Steve slow'
```

Note there is only 1 space between 'Steve' and 'slow'.

How do I do that (preferably in 1 line)?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
[name, quest, favorite_color, speed].reject(&:empty?).join(' ')
```

Comment: When I test this, I get the following error: "Error on line 5: wrong argument type Symbol (expected Proc)"   What am I missing?

Comment: Probably you're using Ruby <1.8.7. Try `[name, quest, favorite_color, speed].reject{|s| s.empty?}.join(' ')`

Comment: What version of Ruby? Could also try:
[name,quest,favorite_color,speed].reject {|s| s.empty?}.join(' ')

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Ruby 1.8.2 BTW.  Thanks guys!

Comment: That worked great for me. Just had to replace `empty?` with `blank?` which is necessary if your list of values may contain nil.

Comment: Could also use `.compact` in place of `reject` -     `[name,quest,favorite_color,speed].compact.join(' ')`

Comment: @RichardPeck `compact` removes elements that are `nil`, the elements that have empty strings would still remain.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 22):

Try `[name,quest,favorite_color,speed].join(' ').squeeze(' ')`

Comment: This will only pull out spaces.  But if there are spaces in the individual string, I can't have them removed.

Comment: It won't pull out spaces in the individual string, only multiple consecutive spaces. This may or may not be a problem for you. If this is some sort of language parser, I would count it as a plus.

Comment: There is a very good chance there will never be multiple consecutive spaces in the initial strings, but I can't risk that.

Comment: You can also use a non-space character for 'join' and 'squeeze' (one that will never appear in your input) and then replace all instances of that character with a space.

Comment: It was fastest by a significant margin (~50%) in my testing.  Platform? Proof?

Comment: @David Upvote for asking a moderately beginner ruby question, but actually understanding the ramifications of various answers.

Comment: @David, I don't understand why you're worried about tidying spaces if you might have spaces in the strings. Are you sure you're specifying the proper delimiter? Should you be quoting the values?`

Comment: +1 @bta's comment.  @Myrddin Thx.  I am a beginner in Ruby, but I'm learning.   @glenn: I have to accurately pull over the original strings.  If it wasn't possible to do that, I would have just left the extra spaces in.

Answer (score 5):

You can use inject:

```
[name,quest,favorite_color,speed].inject("") {|k,v| v.empty? ? k : k << " " << v }.strip
```

Comment: +1 for a working answer, although it's less easy to read (and thus upkeep) than the others.