# how to give whitespace in ruby slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I want to seperate currency and total with whitespace.

Please suggest me a solution 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
p
strong Total:
span
    = @order.currency
    = humanized_money_with_symbol @order.total_paisas/100
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby concatenate strings and add spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434885/ruby-concatenate-strings-and-add-spaces)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can solve this with string interpolation, by doing something like this:

```
p
strong Total:
span
    = "#{@order.currency} #{humanized_money_with_symbol @order.total_paisas/100}"
```

Or with a non-breaking space (nbsp) like this:

```
p
strong Total:
span
    = @order.currency
    | &nbsp;
    = humanized_money_with_symbol @order.total_paisas/100
```

Comment: How on earth is this better than HTML :///

Answer (score 16):

You can also use Slim output `=>` or `=<`

https://github.com/slim-template/slim#output-

Use trailing space on the first output

```
p
strong Total:
span
    => @order.currency
    = humanized_money_with_symbol @order.total_paisas/100
```

or use leading space on the second output

```
p
strong Total:
span
    = @order.currency
    =< humanized_money_with_symbol @order.total_paisas/100
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
p
strong Total:
span
  = [@order.currency, humanized_money_with_symbol @order.total_paisas/100].join(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is special syntax for [verbatim text with trailing space](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#verbatim-text-with-trailing-white-space-),
and that syntax is just a single quotation mark:

```
= @user.first_name
'
= @user.last_name
```

`| &nbsp;`, `join(' ')` and string interpolation are nothing but workarounds.